# Blazor Client Size - Should you add wwwroot/css to the .gitignore file?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, .net-5, blazor-client-side

I've been playing with Blazor Client Side and I have some questions about the basic project setup.

Should I be committing everything in `\Client\wwwroot\css\`?

It contains two libraries

1. Bootstrap 4
2. Open Iconic

I would imagine they are managed through Nuget packages, which means it should pull the version specified when you build?

How does this all work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No these are static directories/files unrelated to any Nuget Packages.  They are just what comes with the template for CSS formatting.   So don't .gitignore them.  There's a short article [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5289921/Blazor-and-CSS-Frameworks) covering CSS in Blazor which shows you one way of setting up CSS in Blazor using SASS and covers Component based Scoped CSS.